# HTTP connection with authentication parameters fails

Tags: http, go

go 1.19

I am trying to connect to a server running on another machine on my network. The response I get back tells me there is an error, and the log file on the server indicates that the problem is an incorrect password. However, I am passing the correct password.

Here is the segment of code that I am using:

```
bodyParams := "{\"param1\":\"val1\", \"param2\":\"val2\", \"param3\":\"val3\"}"
requestBody, e := json.Marshal (bodyParams)

request, _ := http.NewRequest ("POST", "http://192.168.1.31:8972/", bytes.NewBuffer (requestBody))
request.Header.Set ("Content-Type", "application/json")
request.SetBasicAuth ("username", "password")

client := http.Client { Timeout: time.Duration (5 * time.Second) }
response, f := client.Do (request)

body, g := ioutil.ReadAll (response.Body)

response.Body.Close ()
```

I am very new to go but I got this code from various examples. I think the only thing that doesn't work is the authentication.

Are there characters that can't be included in the password in go? I can connect using the same password in C++ so I know it can't be the password itself, but maybe there is some restriction in go? The C++ code that works uses `curl` and the `CURLOPT_USERPWD` option to set the username and password. Does go have an equivalent to `CURLOPT_USERPWD`?

Any ideas on how to solve this problem would be much appreciated.

Comment: This code should work if the client handles basic auth correctly.

Answer (score 0):

There were a few things wrong with my original attempt at doing this.

First, I was marshaling the JSON string which didn't need to be done. I suspect this was the main reason it wasn't working, not the authentication code as I had earlier suspected.

Second, I was using `bytes.NewBuffer` but `strings.NewReader` is needed when we are passing a string.

Third, `ioutil.ReadAll` has been deprecated and we are supposed to use `io.ReadAll` now.

So, this is a modification of the code above that I was able to get working.

```
bodyParams := "{\"param1\":\"val1\", \"param2\":\"val2\", \"param3\":\"val3\"}"

request, _ := http.NewRequest ("POST", "http://192.168.1.31:8972/", strings.NewReader (bodyParams))
request.Header.Set ("Content-Type", "application/json")
request.SetBasicAuth ("username", "password")

client := http.Client { Timeout: time.Duration (5 * time.Second) }
response, _ := client.Do (request)

body, _ := io.ReadAll (response.Body)

response.Body.Close ()
```